# Postgres, Prisma Working Fine One Day, 'P1001 Error: Can't Reach Database' the next

Tags: postgresql, prisma

For this project, I am using a prisma / Postgres database. I have made no changes to my code, and I have pulled a coworkers working version of the code to no avail. I am unable to do anything with the database, I cannot migrate, I cannot run mutations, and I cannot even open the psql console, as every command is met with

```
P1001: Can't reach database server at localhost:5432

Please make sure your database server is running at localhost:5432
```

I am not sure what I could have possibly done, I don't know enough about ports or even the contents of app.json well enough to have messed anything up. Now, no mutations can go through.
Interestingly enough, this all happened after I ran `npx primsa migrate deploy` on the **deployed** database which is on a EC2 VM from AWS. Since then, the native app associated with the database refuses to work, though it is worth nothing that the webapp connects to the deployed database just fine. This being said, nothing works locally, as the database / Port / Server don't exist anymore according to my machine, which makes no sense. I have no idea how to try to re-spin it, or why every single query / mutation from my Native App now ONLy returns `Response not successful: Received status code 400` despite it having the same exact syntax it did when it worked, as well as the WebApp having the same syntax and server (ExpressJS). Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score -1):

The error code `400` refers to a bad request coming from the client: too large request, malformed syntax, invalid request message framing, etc.

First step: make sure that your database server is indeed running. Try connecting to it with other SQL Clients or Libraries. Sometimes Prisma is just being difficult.

Second thing: are you hosting the database on the local server? I can assume you are because of the localhost. Make sure no other programs are using this port or maybe waiting for it.

Sorry if this doesn't help. Good luck!